# AWS DynamoDB filterExpression does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a startTime and endTime field in a stream table.  My scan parameter is:

```
{"TableName":"streams","Limit":"10","FilterExpression":"startTime >= :start_time AND endTime <= :end_time","ExpressionAttributeValues":{":start_time":{"N":"1449446488"},":end_time":{"N":"1449453688"}}}
```

My data startTime is 1449448560 and endTime is 1449452160.

I don't understand why it does not work when running in AWS Lambda function.

[image: It is working fine using the console filter.]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after I removed the "Limit" field.